# kubuntu to debian 12, (11 or 10...) freezes all the time with Firefox 115

Tags: debian, kde, firefox, wayland, freeze

This is a summary of the problems encountered during the last week in which seeking to avoid *Kubuntu updates*, I chose to try several versions of **Debian**, *without luck*.

I write this query for those who are experiencing similar situations, and in some way it can help them solve problems. Mine was not solved, so I ask the community for any ideas and help.

Hardware:
Intel(R) **Core(TM) i7-3770** CPU @ 3.40GHz / External Clock: 800MHz / Turbo: 3.90GHz
MoBo: Intel **DH77KC** LGA1155
Memory: 16GB
(yes! its an old equipment but very, very stable)

We start by giving the new **Debian 12** (Bookworm) a chance, since we have a previous experience with a modest fileserver installed with debian 10 (buster) 4.19.0.18 on a core i5 (oldie) and it has not caused any problems in the last 2 years. Therefore we assumed that for a more "modern" computer (core i7 with 9 years), the bookworm could work well, taking into consideration (as usual) the *kernel*, which could have certain conflicts with some drivers.

**The installation went without problems**, first boots and configuration went well.
The **Kernel installed was 6.1.0-12**
**KDE Plasma version 5.27.5**, Frameworks: 5.103.0, **Qt version 5.15.8** and the graphic platform is Wayland...

Everything was fine until we started working with **Firefox 115.3**...
**For no reason, and at any time, all system FREEZE...**
We reviewed information in several forums and they pointed to conflicts between Firefox versions with Wayland and KDE...

To avoid possible conflicts with Firefox, we installed **Brave Browser**...
Sounds good, at the beginning, but then, 20 minutes later: FREEZE... again...

All **hardware**, memory, hard disks, etc. **were checked and no problems were found.**

We thought it could be a conflict with the debian kernel and KDE versions installed, or maybe Wayland and KDE...

For this reason we started several installations from scratch (and different versions of debian/kernel: deb11, deb10...), and because the freezes continue, we start to think about changing the display manager (DM) to avoid potential conflicts that Wayland could generate... so, we looked for an installation that included the light DM Xfce and then selected KDE with X11. (because we love KDE, not gnome).

However, after many hours of testings and installations: freeze again... despite the Firefox version you try, or if you change it for Brave or Konqueror... sooner or later it freezes... and freeze forever...

**is Debian a problem?, KDE?, Firefox and others?**

We looked for more information and similar situations, and it pointed out that it could be a conflict with **Intel's Self Refresh Panel** (PSR), similar problems that was seen years ago with diferent kernels and distros, however, despite the fact that the PSR was disabled:

$ echo "options i915 enable_psr=0" >> /etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf

$ sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

the freeze continue...

so, after 2 or 3 days spent on installations and testing, i said: "ok, i am tired..."

Options? mmmhhh... ok, lets try a different flavor: **openSUSE** was good, years ago.
¿why not try again?

Yes!: The only way to have a stable system again was by installing openSUSE Leap 15.5.

(but as you may feel, this is not a real solution for the problem posted...)

openSUSE 15.5 works very well now, but of course, as you may know *the SUSE community made some 'announcements' since last year indicating that they will apparently leave aside the development of opensuse* in the desktop versions,
So, for me is not a bad idea to look at other options for next year if opensuse dead.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and recommendations around this case!

Comment: Not sure why you seem to think it's a Firefox issue since Brave (Chromium based I believe) also freezes. Have you tried Chrome/Chromium also (same pigs with different liptstick)? Chances are if Brave freezes, they will too. You haven't mentioned the GPU in your system. I've never had an issue with any browser in Debian. But then, I use Gnome (Wayland) or XFCE (X11). So, based on my very limited and completely subjective experience, the issue you have is probably KDE - or the GPU. Have you considered at least checking Gnome to see if the freezes still occur?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jaromanda.  GPU is the intel HD4000.

Why not try Gnome?, oh..., no thanks, dont like it.  But you are right, probably is the combination of KDE + Debian (Wayland or X11 indistinctly)
Thanks!

Comment: Can you check it with an external video card?

Comment: no, we have not tested with a PCI video card, since we have been working with linux (ubuntu, mint, opensuse, kubuntu) for more than 10 years and never had problems with integrated graphics.
We could do the test, but if that solves problems we would be saying that the Debian kernel worked well with Intel graphics 5 years ago, but not anymore... 
Maybe it's Wayland...